# Python: How to read images from zip file in memory?

Tags: python, io, buffer, python-imaging-library, zip

I have seen variations of this question, but not in this exact context. What I have is a file called 100-Test.zip which contains 100 .jpg images. I want to open this file in memory and process each file doing PIL operations. The rest of the code is already written, I just want to concentrate on getting from the zip file to the first PIL image. This is what the code looks like now from suggestions I've gathered from reading other questions, but it's not working. Can you guys take a look and help?

```
import zipfile
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image

imgzip = open('100-Test.zip', 'rb')
z = zipfile.ZipFile(imgzip)
data = z.read(z.namelist()[0])
dataEnc = StringIO(data)
img = Image.open(dataEnc)

print img
```

But I am getting this error when I run it:

```
 IOError: cannot identify image file <StringIO.StringIO instance at
 0x7f606ecffab8>
```

Alternatives: I have seen other sources saying to use this instead:

```
image_file = StringIO(open("test.jpg",'rb').read())
im = Image.open(image_file)
```

But the problem is I'm not opening a file, it's already in memory inside the data variable. I also tried using `dataEnc = StringIO.read(data)` but got this error:

```
TypeError: unbound method read() must be called with StringIO instance as 
first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Comment: Your first example works fine for me, you could also `z = zipfile.ZipFile('100-Test.zip')`

Comment: @alfredox did you check if `z.namelist()[0]` is an image file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham so you made no changes to the code and it worked? I am not sure what I am missing then, because I am getting those errors.

Comment: @ozgur I just assumed that it contained the first file inside the zipfile, I am not sure how to test that this is an image.

Comment: Yeah as @ozgur was hinting at, the issue is probably that whatever the first item in the zipfile is is not a valid image file (or at least not one your PIL knows how to decode).  Just printing `z.namelist` should give you an idea of which file you are actually opening

Comment: Thanks guys!! That was it, since the files where actually zipped inside of a directory, it had an empty line in the namelist for that directory. so I added a check to see if it was a jpg and that fixed it! I'll put the code in the original question.

Comment: alfredox: You should take the answer out of your question and post it as answer — you can answer your own questions on SO (after a waiting period) and even accept them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the problem was there was an extra empty element in namelist() due to the images being zipped inside a direcotory insde the zip file. Here is the full code that will check for that and iterate through the 100 images.

```
import zipfile
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image
import imghdr

imgzip = open('100-Test.zip')
zippedImgs = zipfile.ZipFile(imgzip)

for i in xrange(len(zippedImgs.namelist())):
    print "iter", i, " ",
    file_in_zip = zippedImgs.namelist()[i]
    if (".jpg" in file_in_zip or ".JPG" in file_in_zip):
        print "Found image: ", file_in_zip, " -- ",
        data = zippedImgs.read(file_in_zip)
        dataEnc = StringIO(data)
        img = Image.open(dataEnc)
        print img
    else:
        print ""
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 10):

There is no need to use StringIO. `zipfile` can read image file in memory. The following loops through all images in your .zip file:

```
import zipfile
from PIL import Image

imgzip = zipfile.ZipFile("100-Test.zip")
inflist = imgzip.infolist()

for f in inflist:
    ifile = imgzip.open(f)
    img = Image.open(ifile)
    print(img)
    # display(img)
```

Comment: I just tried this idea on a large compressed TIFF file (1024*768*116). While it may well be good for small files, it is FAR too SLOW for large files. (>20 min vs 6 sec for uncompressed) Nice idea though...

Comment: The speed depends on application. In a test I ran `Pillow` took 0.26s to read a 1280x1040 16-bit tif image from the zipped file. `tifffile` took .13 s to read the same file. Unzipping the archive and then reading with tifffile took 0.24s.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue, thanks for @alfredox, I modified the answer, use io.BytesIO not StringIo in python3.

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file)
for i in range(len(z.namelist())):

    file_in_zip = z.namelist()[i]
    if (".jpg" in file_in_zip or ".JPG" in file_in_zip):

        data = z.read(file_in_zip)
        dataEnc = io.BytesIO(data)
        img = Image.open(dataEnc)
        print(img)
```

Answer (score 2):

cv2.imdecode() version:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_data_path, "r") as z:
    for img_name in z.namelist():
        buf = z.read(name)
        np_buf = np.frombuffer(buf, np.uint8)
        img = cv2.imdecode(np_buf, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        # Saving image as an example.
        cv2.imwrite(name, img)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to work on pixel data then you can load an image stream data from zip file as numpy array keeping the original data shape (i.e. 32x32 RGB) following the steps:

1. use zipfile to get the ZipExtFile format
2. use PIL.Image to convert ZipExtFile into image like data structure
3. convert PIL.image into numpy array

No need to reshape numpy array with original data shape because PIL.Image already has the information. So the output will be a numpy array with shape=(32,32,3)

```
import numpy as np
import zipfile
from PIL import Image

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_data_path, "r") as zip_data:
    content_list = zip_data.namelist()
    for name_file in content_list:
        img_bytes = zip_data.open(name_file)          # 1
        img_data = Image.open(img_bytes)              # 2
        # ndarray with shape=(32,32,3)
        image_as_array = np.array(img_data, np.uint8) # 3
```